# Unwanted character in Excel Cell In Python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, character

I am facing an issue with setting a value of Excel Cell.
I get data from a table cell in MS-Word Document(dcx) and print it on output console.

Problem is that the data of the cell is just a word, "Hour", with no apparent other leading or trailing printable character like white-spaces. But when I print it using python's print() function, it shows some unexpected character, more like a small "?" in a rectangle.

I don't know where does it come from.

And when I write the same variable that holds the word, "Hour", to an Excel cell it shows a bold dot(**.**)  in the cell.

What can be the problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

I Am Using Python 3.2 And PyWin32 3.2 On Win7.
Thanks.

Comment: If you iterate over every character in the string and run `ord(char)` on each, what values are returned?

Comment: Try `print repr(value)` instead of `print value`.

Comment: @sarnold, It returns 72 111 117 114 13.

Comment: @bossylobster, print(repr(value)) returns:
'Hour\r'
Can you please explain what repr() does?
I am new to python.

Comment: "Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`..."  http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#repr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `value.rstrip('\r\n')` to remove any carriage returns (`\r`) or newlines (`\n`) at the end of your string `value`.

Comment: `\x07` is equivalent to `\a` which is a system beep. I'm not sure how that made it into your string.

Comment: Is there any way to strip all those special characters like, \t, \a, \n and others.? I mean without using all of them in the strip function?

Comment: No. The important thing here, and in the future when you are programming, is understanding why they look that way. Why don't you post the code you are using to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem when I get data from a table in word document. What I did to solve this problem is to write a small function that removes all these unnecessary characters:

```
import re

def removechars(cellvalue):
    text = re.sub(r"[\r\n\t\x07\x0b]", "", cellvalue)
    return text
```

Then I use :

```
value = table.Cell(Row = 1, Column = 1).Range.Text
value = removechars(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above mate.