# Printing HTML tags around strings

Tags: python, html

I am trying to wrap common HTML tags around a number of strings, but am getting very strange outputs.

```py
def function():
    return string

tempStr =  function()

output = ("<h1>" + tempStr + "</h1>")
```

returns

```
</h1>empStr
```

is /h some sort of escape sequence?

EDIT:   As requested

`output = retrieveTxt()`

`print(output)`

Output: `"The progress point code"`

`print("<h1>" + output + "</h1>")`

Output: `"</h1>he progress point code"`

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your case, and what techstack you are using and sample input and output or error ?

Comment: 1. I am not sure what you mean by tech-stack. The input is a simply a ```string``` and the output is said ```string``` concatenated as such ```<h1> string </h1>```

Comment: As you are trying to print HTML tags, I though maybe you're using any web framework and that's why asked that question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you forgetting to pass the parameter?

it works fine for me.

```
def function(string):
    return string

tempStr =  function('bye')

output = ("<h1>" + tempStr + "</h1>")
```

getting the expected output `"<h1>bye</h1>"`

Comment: My function doesn't require a parameter, the string is obtained inside of the function itself which is working perfectly. Strange that ti works for you, with little difference to my version.

Comment: I can replicate your results too without using my function. It seems that the docx package I am using is causing a variation in the strings it reads from Word Documents. Will troubleshoot this.

Comment: I tried to use ```repr(retrieveTxt())``` and it returned ```'The progress point code\r\r\x07'```. Any idea what the ```/r``` are doing?. This leads me to believe that this is the cause of the issue

Comment: @TheMob \r\r\x07 appears special characters returned while reading text from doc as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423593/unwanted-character-in-excel-cell-in-python

Comment: Thanks heaps for this link. Will try to refine my searches next time.